# text From the clipbord is pasted twice in a ListBox in VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net, copy-paste, paste

I want to paste data from the clipbord in a vb.net using this code:

```
 Private Sub MenuItemPaste_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuItemPaste.Click

    Dim items() As String = Clipboard.GetText.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)  ' 
    ListBox1.Items.AddRange(items)
```

Why Does the selected text is pasted 2 times?

Comment: Are you sure the data doesn't have the repeat in it?  Grab the text first and output it: `Dim data As String = Clipboard.GetText()`, followed by `Debug.Print(data)`.  Then split the "data" variable instead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct and there is no reason to paste the text twice! I guess you need to clear the `ListBox1` first before adding text to it in the `MenuItemPaste_Click` event. So you can try using the following code :

```
ListBox1.Items.Clear()
Dim items() As String = Clipboard.GetText.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)  ' 
ListBox1.Items.AddRange(items)
```

Comment: Yes, indeed my code was correct, and your answer was useful, that's why i was confident in this code so i figured out the problem in the beginnig

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers in such short time. In fact. I figured out what was the problem (after many revisions) and it was really a silly mistake. I forgot that, in the beginning of the code, (on Load), i have added a handler `AddHandler MenuItemPaste.Click, AddressOf MenuItemPaste_Click` after that, for doing the `MenuItemPaste_Click sub` I wrote it in that way:

```
Private Sub MenuItemPaste_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuItemPaste.Click

      Dim items() As String = Clipboard.GetText.Split(New String() {Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)   
      ListBox1.Items.AddRange(items)

End Sub
```

So in that way, the paste on the event was duplicated